# Why I got 'TS2345: Argument of type 'IInitialState' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.' in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I'm learning typescript and got loads of errors.

At `useReducer` hook I got the following TS Error:

> TS2345: Argument of type 'IInitialState' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.

My code is:

```
...

interface IMovie {
  Poster: string;
  Title: string;
  Year: string;
}

interface IInitialState {
  loading: boolean;
  movies: IMovie[];
  errorMessage: string | null
}

interface IAction {
  type: string;
  payload?: any,
  error?: string
}

const initialState: IInitialState = {
  loading: true,
  movies: [],
  errorMessage: null
};

const reducer = (state: IInitialState, action: IAction) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SEARCH_MOVIE_REQUEST':
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true,
        errorMessage: null
      };
    case 'SEARCH_MOVIE_SUCCESS':
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        movies: action.payload
      };
    case 'SEARCH_MOVIE_FAILURE':
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        errorMessage: action.error
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  return (
    <div className="App">
     ...
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that `reducer` isn't quite a valid reducer, as its return type is not quite assignable to `IInitialState`.  It's *close*, but not close enough for React's type definitions to work on it.

If you try to inspect what it returns, you'll see it's of the type

```
{
    loading: boolean;
    movies: any;
    errorMessage: string | null;
} | {
    loading: boolean;
    errorMessage: string | undefined;
    movies: IMovie[];
}
```

The problem there is that the second union element has `errorMessage` as `string | undefined` instead of `string | null` as needed.  It looks like your `SEARCH_MOVIE_FAILURE` case returns `action.error`, which is of type `string | undefined` and not `string | null`.  You might want to change it to something like this:

```
case 'SEARCH_MOVIE_FAILURE':
  return {
    ...state,
    loading: false,
    errorMessage: action.error || null // here
  };
```

That should fix your problem, I guess.  It's unfortunate that the error message you get is so opaque; the problem is with `reducer`, not really with `initialState`.  Oh well.  Hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=1&ts=3.6.3&ssl=49&ssc=9&pln=44&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQNwCwAUKJLHAN5wCuqW2AJp1xYocAL5wiJcpTwwyjRsAB2MYQTxY4ASQCyEAG7BNbRnDgAFCKlVQAXHGtRlAc3oMzAFWAwANlnuOLm5mAJo4dg4wTkqujKIKTCpqGtpaSt7AyD4AyjDIquymcD4QyHwu9gBGEBB+yErBcCAGRqj2ui1YANoAuo3CxFA6WKioyM7+kdHOcAA+cEqcPj5xCco26kLaAIL4wBBKhe5wMACeYJOBMY1gyKclZQD89vWnADRFA9DPUy6rDIxcAdrHBlBksrl8pMtGlwTk8gUALxHMwPcoxexRThYD7HZqGEb2Xq4sxfIYjMYTeyLZZxNwJQHA+CUARCETIgAU1ih7VhMEy8KhbxQewO7V2-IOAEo4IiAHwohwAd28uAAFnAObJ9koAHRnC4ykzHMy4NCaMjZACi2wwAGEABIAfR0AHkAGpaK1OjBWgCKAFUrdkPGRbEUzGZKDBOFBDsbI4m4LqU9zVCSk6jSujnJioNiM5mycNRuNJjSVibI6JGqbzeRrbbHS6PV6ndkA3a7cHsmGI5Ho7H4-3EyndWmcSPI2iKhIsjxC0n8a0XqK9bd7tmpzX+2aeA2bfbnW7Pd6AGLbLQAGQDvr7VajWBjccVmbHE8XiZnGLnPgXU9JKBBhLSlJm1A5dTJOZ5grOAAHo4LgNVhCwbdazgPgsHUJYYHDB84EHF8J0aeIGB3AEKKBJQQW2MAwHsbBZF1M87VlTUZXlRUqJBLoPww4BUFuGB1R6NjuF4LBWWEDkWUEYRhTBfkIQRLApXpY5CMODl+wAHnKfQ4FwHw0FQAA5ZAQCwREACJaLAay5RHMddLg-THOONS6SAA)

Comment: I used your advice in `SEARCH_MOVIE_FAILURE` case and it works，I didn't realize that the value of  `errorMessage` might be `undefined`, tks a lot!